# Passing data into Google Spreadsheet from JSON response

Tags: json, google-apps-script

I'm building a script to call the FB api and import the response into a google sheet. After using `JSON.stringify` I have the following response :

```
    {
   "data":[
      {
         "id":"page_id/insights/page_impressions/day",
         "name":"page_impressions",
         "period":"day",
         "values":[
            {
               "value":26023596,
               "end_time":"2016-11-17T08:00:00+0000"
            },
            {
               "value":24447386,
               "end_time":"2016-11-18T08:00:00+0000"
            },
            {
               "value":31057386,
               "end_time":"2016-11-19T08:00:00+0000"
            }
         ],
         "title":"Daily Total Impressions",
         "description":"Daily: The number of impressions seen of any content associated with your Page. (Total Count)"
      },
      {
         "id":"page_id/insights/page_impressions/week",
         "name":"page_impressions",
         "period":"week",
         "values":[
            {
               "value":233007217,
               "end_time":"2016-11-17T08:00:00+0000"
            },
            {
               "value":200263630,
               "end_time":"2016-11-18T08:00:00+0000"
            },
            {
               "value":194289364,
               "end_time":"2016-11-19T08:00:00+0000"
            }
         ],
         "title":"Weekly Total Impressions",
         "description":"Weekly: The number of impressions seen of any content associated with your Page. (Total Count)"
      },
      {
         "id":"page_id/insights/page_impressions/days_28",
         "name":"page_impressions",
         "period":"days_28",
         "values":[
            {
               "value":867302439,
               "end_time":"2016-11-17T08:00:00+0000"
            },
            {
               "value":868201060,
               "end_time":"2016-11-18T08:00:00+0000"
            },
            {
               "value":874965509,
               "end_time":"2016-11-19T08:00:00+0000"
            }
         ],
         "title":"28 Days Total Impressions",
         "description":"28 Days: The number of impressions seen of any content associated with your Page. (Total Count)"
      }
   ],
   "paging":{
      "previous":"https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/page_id/insights/page_impressions?access_token=my_token&since=1479068112&until=1479327312",
      "next":"https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/page_id/insights/page_impressions?access_token=my_token&since=1479586512&until=1479845712"
   }
}
```

I would like to import the value for `Daily Total Impressions`, `Weekly Total Impressions` and `28 Days Total Impressions` in my google sheet however I'm not sure how should I proceed. I know how I can access specific value, like this for exemple : `data.data[0].values[0].value`. but that's all. Don't really know what I should do next.

Ideally I would like to be able to create a new array and push the data in there. (`var data = []; data.push(???)`)

but I'm totally lost in the multiple array/object.

thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about following script. "jsondata" is your data. Please use this script as a container Bound Script of spreadsheet.

```
var data = JSON.parse(jsondata);
var ar = [];
for (var i in data.data){
    for (var k in data.data[i].values) {
        ar.push([data.data[i].title, data.data[i].values[k].value]);
    }
}
ass = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
ass.getRange('a1').offset(0, 0, ar.length, ar[0].length).setValues(ar);
```

The result is as follows.

[image]